# How to re -run the link function of directive after model binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have directive with following code

```
 app.directive('formControl', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                // Add class filled to form-control's that have a value
                if (element.val()) {
                    element.parent().addClass('filled');

                }

                element.bind('blur', function (e) {
                    var input = angular.element(e.currentTarget);
                    if (input.val()) {
                        input.parent().addClass('filled');
                    } else {
                        input.parent().removeClass('filled');
                    }
                    input.parent().removeClass('active');
                }).bind('focus', function (e) {

                    var input = angular.element(e.currentTarget);
                    input.parent().addClass('active');
                }).bind('change',function(e) {
                   // Add class filled to form-control's that have a value
                    var input = angular.element(e.currentTarget);
                    input.parent().addClass('active');
                } );

            }
        };
    });
```

// Sample directive

```
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="lastname" class="control-label">Phone number</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phonenumber"  id="phonenumber" ng-model="user.phone_number" required maxlength="75">
   </div>
```

The purpose of this directive is very simple, add some css class to the target object based on few events and value status..

This directive will work fine if it hasnt any value. but if i have a value populated via model binding (not from keyboard ,via model binding). It wont work.

**Ie. I want to execute code "input.parent().addClass('active');"    when the directive/input field  populated the  value via model binding**

I tried the change event but it is not working

Comment: You need to use directive ng-change="yourFunction()", whenever you change input value u get that function run and you may attach any action you want to it.
And event is working just you need to have in your controllser $scope.yourfunction = function(){ sthhere }

Comment: @PawełSmołka,I have more than 100 instances of this directive, so attaching the same function to every instance is tedious

Comment: Have you considered simple scope.watch? instead of change it triggers disregarding who changed value

Comment: not sure why you aren't using internal form validation object to drive this. Need to stop thinking about the dom first and let angular models drive the dom

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to somehow get hold of the binding set up by `ng-model` and react when the model changes. `ng-model` exposes its [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController), which in turn exposes the model value, which you can `$watch`. Something like this:

```
 app.directive('formControl', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        require: '?ngModel',  // the (optional) ng-model on the same element
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            [...]

            if (ngModel) {
                scope.$watch(function() {
                    return ngModel.$modelValue;
                }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                    input.parent().addClass('active');
                })
            }
        }
    };
});
```